# Breaking apart a sin wave but phase doesn't seem to match up sometimes

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, phase

I originally posted this in physics stack exchange but they requested it be posted here as well....
I am trying to create a known signal with a known wavelength, amplitude, and phase. I then want to break this signal apart into all of its frequencies, find amplitudes, phases, and wavelengths for each frequency, then create equations for each frequency based on these new wavelengths, amplitudes, and phases. In theory, the equations should be identical to the individual signals. However, they are not. I am almost positive it is an issue with phase but I cannot figure out how to resolve it. I will post the exact code to reproduce this below. Please help as my phase, wavelength, and amplitudes will vary once I get more complicated signals so it need to work for any combination of these.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack

# create signal
time_vec = np.arange(1, 11, 1)
wavelength = 1/.1
phase = 0
amp = 10
created_signal = amp * np.sin((2 * np.pi / wavelength * time_vec) + phase)

# plot it
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10,6))
axs[0].plot(time_vec, created_signal, label='exact_data')

# get fft and freq array
sig_fft = fftpack.fft(created_signal)
sample_freq = fftpack.fftfreq(created_signal.size, d=1)

# do inverse fft and verify same curve as original signal. This is fine!
filtered_signal = fftpack.ifft(sig_fft)
filtered_signal += np.mean(created_signal)

# create individual signals for each frequency
filtered_signals = []
for i in range(len(sample_freq)):
    high_freq_fft = sig_fft.copy()
    high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) < np.nanmin(sample_freq[i])] = 0
    high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) > np.nanmax(sample_freq[i])] = 0
    filtered_sig = fftpack.ifft(high_freq_fft)
    filtered_sig += np.mean(created_signal)
    filtered_signals.append(filtered_sig)

# get phase, amplitude, and wavelength for each individual frequency
sig_size = len(created_signal)
wavelength = []
ph = []
amp = []
indices = []
for j in range(len(sample_freq)):
    wavelength.append(1 / sample_freq[j])
    indices.append(int(sig_size * sample_freq[j]))
for j in indices:
    phase = np.arctan2(sig_fft[j].imag, sig_fft[j].real)
    ph.append([phase])
    amp.append([np.sqrt((sig_fft[j].real * sig_fft[j].real) + (sig_fft[j].imag * sig_fft[j].imag)) / (sig_size / 2)])

# create an equation for each frequency based on each phase, amp, and wavelength found from above.
def eqn(filtered_si, wavelength, time_vec, phase, amp):
    return amp * np.sin((2 * np.pi / wavelength * time_vec) + phase)
def find_equations(filtered_signals_mean, high_freq_fft, wavelength, filtered_signals, time_vec, ph, amp):
    equations = []
    for i in range(len(wavelength)):
        temp = eqn(filtered_signals[i], wavelength[i], time_vec, ph[i], amp[i])
        equations.append(temp + filtered_signals_mean)
    return equations

filtered_signals_mean = np.abs(np.mean(filtered_signals))
equations = find_equations(filtered_signals_mean, sig_fft, wavelength, 
                                      filtered_signals, time_vec, ph, amp)

# at this point each equation, for each frequency should match identically each signal from each frequency,
# however, the phase seems wrong and they do not match!!??
axs[0].plot(time_vec, filtered_signal, '--', linewidth=3, label='filtered_sig_combined')
axs[1].plot(time_vec, filtered_signals[1], label='filtered_sig[-1]')
axs[1].plot(time_vec, equations[1], label='equations[-1]')
axs[0].legend()
axs[1].legend()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

These are issues with your code:

> ```py
> filtered_signal = fftpack.ifft(sig_fft)
> filtered_signal += np.mean(created_signal)
> ```

This only works because `np.mean(created_signal)` is approximately zero. The IFFT already takes the DC component into account, the zero frequency describes the mean of the signal.

> ```py
> filtered_signals = []
> for i in range(len(sample_freq)):
>    high_freq_fft = sig_fft.copy()
>    high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) < np.nanmin(sample_freq[i])] = 0
>    high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) > np.nanmax(sample_freq[i])] = 0
>    filtered_sig = fftpack.ifft(high_freq_fft)
>    filtered_sig += np.mean(created_signal)
>    filtered_signals.append(filtered_sig)
> ```

Here you are, in the first half of the iterations, going through all the frequencies, taking both the negative and positive frequencies into account. For example, when `i=1`, you take both the -0.1 and the 0.1 frequencies. The second half of the iterations you are applying the IFFT to a zero signal, none of the `np.abs(sample_freq)` are smaller than zero by definition.

So the `filtered_signals[1]` contains a sine wave constructed by both the -0.1 and the 0.1 frequency components. This is good. Otherwise it would be a complex-valued function.

> ```py
> for j in range(len(sample_freq)):
>    wavelength.append(1 / sample_freq[j])
>    indices.append(int(sig_size * sample_freq[j]))
> ```

Here the second half of the `indices` array contains negative values. Not sure what you were planning with this, but it causes subsequent code to index from the end of the array.

> ```py
> for j in indices:
>    phase = np.arctan2(sig_fft[j].imag, sig_fft[j].real)
>    ph.append([phase])
>    amp.append([np.sqrt((sig_fft[j].real * sig_fft[j].real) + (sig_fft[j].imag * sig_fft[j].imag)) / (sig_size / 2)])
> ```

Here, because the indices are not the same as the `j` in the previous loop, `phase[j]` doesn't always correspond to `wavelength[j]`, they refer to values from different frequency components in about half the cases. But those cases we shouldn't be evaluating any way. The code assumes a real-valued input, for which the magnitude and phase of only the positive frequencies is sufficient to reconstruct the signal. You should skip all the negative frequencies here.

Next, you build sine waves using the collected information, but using a `time_vec` that starts at 1, not at 0 as the FFT assumes. And therefore the signal is shifted with respect to the expected value. Furthermore, when `phase==0`, you should create an even signal (i.e. a cosine, not a sine).

Thus, changing the following two lines of code will create the correct output:

```py
time_vec = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
```

and

```py
def eqn(filtered_si, wavelength, time_vec, phase, amp):
   return amp * np.cos((2 * np.pi / wavelength * time_vec) + phase)
#                  ^^^
```

Note that these two changes corrects the plotted graph, but doesn't correct all the issues in the code discussed above.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this finally after 2 days of frustration. I still have no idea why this is the way it is so any insight would be great. The solution is to use the phase produced by arctan2(Im, Re) and modify it according to this equation.

```
phase = np.arctan2(sig_fft[j].imag, sig_fft[j].real)    
formula = ((((wavelength[j]) / 2) - 2) * np.pi) / wavelength[j]
ph.append([phase + formula])
```

I had to derive this equation from data but I still do not know why this works. Please let me know. Finally!!